# Opening files Error -36

Tags: finder, time-capsule

I am trying to open files on Time Capsule (not backups) but files will not open in Finder.  I'm receiving error `-36`.  When I copy files to my MacBook Pro, files opened without any problems. **Quick Look** works fine on Time Capsule.

Can anyone please help?

[image: Screenshot GUI error message]

[image: Screenshot Terminal error message]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently and it was due to a problem with the previous version of macOS Sierra supported by acknowledgement by Apple of many similar reported bug in version 10.12.2.

The most recent **update to macOS Sierra 10.12.3 resolved the error -36 with previewing files on the Time Capsule for me, try updating.**

Dot_clean did not work for me but connecting the TC via SMB was a simple workaround until Apple sorted the issue out.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by using `dot_clean`.

1. Launch the Terminal
2. At the command prompt, type: `dot_clean /Path/To/Directory/With/Problem/`
3. When `dot_clean` is finished, attempt to open the file again and it should succeed with no error code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix:

Connect the TC manually (via SMB).
Finder -> Connect Server -> smb://server name or IP (enter password if needed)
Seems, that the OS connects the TC by default via 'afp' and there is something incorrect with the access rights (as the icons/shortcuts) at the desktop are different.

Connect Server is under the "Go" menu.  Here is the sample of the server address I entered: smb://10.0.1.1  (it's the TC IP address).  Then I connect to that server rather than the default TC link.